# innerHTML will not print variable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a problem with printing a variable with `innerHTML` in Firefox. It's a pretty simple code I would have thought and it works fine in Chrome, IE and Safari.

In Firefox, however, it refuses to print the user entered data in the input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />    
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function showVar() {
                document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('myname').value;
            }    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="showVar()"><br><br>
        <div id='name'> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate some help on this as I need this for a class exercise.

Thanks!

Comment: This code works fine for me in Firefox 28. Look in the Firefox console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: It could be because `<input>` are void elements. Try `document.getElementById('name').value = document.getElementById('myname').value;`

Comment: @JackWilliams The `name` is the div he's trying to output the value to, the `myname` is the input.

Comment: What if u use `input type="button"` instead of `input type="submit"` - does it make a difference?

Comment: Disregard my comment then, haha.

Comment: It works for me in firefox 30.0a2, so perhaps it's a bug that will be fixed in a future version?

Comment: Problem fixed up, see my edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, in my version of Firefox, I can't get the code to work using native Javascript.

This JQuery code works (http://jsfiddle.net/yvML8/1/)

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#name").html($("#myname").val());
});
```

But are you allowed to use JQuery?  I know Classes/Unis can be very specific over the use of JQuery.

**Edit: Solution**

Okay, the problem is that your `<script>` tag isn't legal. You need to use `type="text/javascript"`, not `language` in your script header.  I played around with positioning, and it doesn't matter if the script is placed before or after your HTML code.

The full code looks like:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showVar() {

    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('myname').value;

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showVar()"><br><br>
    <div id='name'></div>
</body>
```

Firefox in particular does have issues with `<script>` and `<link>` parameters, and sometimes the other browsers are more lenient.  I have issues myself with this sometimes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! It works, both with jQuery and with the text/javascript as opposed to language :)

Answer (score 1):

the script attribute `language` is not firefox friendly. try using `type="text/javascript"` instead.

Comment: That's exactly the same answer I gave 21 minutes ago...except I gave a JQuery option as well.